# Importing module from another folder. Python 3.3

Tags: import, module, directory

Pretty new to python. Running linux os

I have a folder folder1 with my main program "main.py"

I have a folder folder2 with my module "module.py"

The module has 2 functions in it function1 and function2

Both folders are in the same folder.

How do I import the module.py from folder2 into my main.py in folder1? or do I have to pick out the individual function from module.py somehow?

preferably just import both functions at once

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import sys, os.path

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
+ '/folder2/')
```

Then you can import as usual. Please see the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder/46569406#46569406) to a similar question.